# Can Rails log entries be truncated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I'm using Rails 3.2.8 with PostgreSQL/PostGIS and the rgeo family of gems.  These produce logs with spectacularly long queries, which quickly become GB in size:

```
Region Load (8.8ms)  SELECT name, polygon FROM "region" WHERE "region"."id" = 17 LIMIT 1
(6.2ms)  SELECT st_astext(st_centroid('MULTIPOLYGON (((-111.1779942105267
64.09860899912356, -111.17799400000047 64.09859499912357, -111.17671900000042 
64.098605999123485, -111.17635518181078 64.09860899912356, -111.17538500000043  
...
...many, many, many points ...
...
-111.17799600000035 64.101920999123465, -111.1779940000004 64.10127099912361,
-111.17799500000035 64.09935199912358, -111.17799600000035 64.09872799912365,
-111.1779942105267 64.09860899912356)))'))
```

Is there a builtin way to constrain the length of Rails log entries?  Even better would be a way to constrain just the query part of the log for certain types of queries (ie. geographic queries in this case).

Comment: try to find info here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, a la this (revised) [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/56-the-logger-revised):

```
# config/initializers/log_formatter.rb
class Logger::SimpleFormatter
  def call(severity, time, progname, msg)
    "[#{severity}] #{msg.truncate(200)}\n"
  end
end
```